# how to create inset trigger to add new row in to another table in sybase?

Tags: sql, triggers, sybase

I have three table as customer, customer-log and address.
I want to add new row which consist of foreign key(primary key of customer table) and all columns from address table in to the customer-log table.
can somebody correct this trigger ?

**customer columns:**

```
customerId, addressId, name, auto, type, date
```

**customer-log columns:**

```
customerId, addressId, street, number, city, country
```

**address columns:**

```
addressId, street, number, city, country
```

**Trigger:**

```
create trigger insertCustomerLog 
on customer 
for insert 
if INSERTED.type = 'B'
begin 
    INSERT INTO customer-log
    SELECT INSERTED.customerId,(SELECT * FROM address AS a WHERE INSERTED.addressId = a.addressId)    
end
```

Comment: WEll to start with never use correlated subqueries in a  trigger. And  specify the columns in the insert without a select *, you don;t want ti to break if someone adds a column to address that is not in customer-log.  But what error are you getting or what is the problem you see with the current implementation? (Oh and don't forget to always test triggers with both single record inserts and mulitple record inserts, you can avoind many problems that way).

Comment: I agree with @HLGEM, you should be doing this in whatever piece is doing the insert rather than trying to use a trigger. You would have to order the inserts based on the foreign key though.